# Why is there a sudden change in current between \$t=0^{-}\$ and \$t=0^{+}\$ when an active inductor is connected in series with a relaxed inductor?

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, laplace-transform

[image]

For the above question I drew the corresponding Laplace transform diagram, as follows (didn't draw the switch since it basically open circuit after \$t=0\$):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feURhS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For the inductor on the upper right, note that I plugged in the value of \$i(0^{-})\$ that is, \$3A\$, as that was the current that was flowing through it when the switch was closed for a long time (as \$\frac{12 V}{4\Omega}=3A\$).

The loop equation thus turns out to be:

$$\frac{12}{s}-4I(s)-2sI(s)+6-sI(s)-4I(s)=0$$
$$\implies I(s)=\frac{12+6s}{8s+3s^2}$$

Which on Inverse Laplace transform gives me the actual loop current in time domain as \$i(t)=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-8t/3}\$.

Clearly, \$i(0^{+}) = \lim_{t\to 0^{+}}i(t)=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=2\$. Thus, \$i(0^{+})\$ is quite different from \$i(0^{-})\$, which is \$3\$ (in amperes).

**Why is there a sudden jump in current between \$t=0^{-}\$ and \$t=0^{+}\$ ?**

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 Which assumptions are you talking about? Also what do you mean by "there would be a singularity in voltage in 0 time"?

Comment: V=LdI/dt as dt goes to 0, V goes to 1/0

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 Okay, so what would be the correct way to approach the question?

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 What is HV?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76403/discussion-between-user554252-and-tony-stewart-ee-since-1975).

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 Thanks but could we please talk in the chat for a bit? I have a few confusions regarding what you said

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 I'm not clear about a few things. Firstly, according to you what will be the initial current in the circuit?

Comment: 1H switched goes from 0A to 1.5A exponentially as 2H current goes from 3A to 1.5A exponentially

Comment: I changed a couple values and simulated for you http://tinyurl.com/y85znshw and added series interactive switch  L/R =T is 3H/8 Ohms = 0.375 time constant for yours. You can try both switches

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 Are you trying to say that the current is different for both the inductors even though they're connected **in series**? How's that even possible?

Comment: They both go to 1.5A = 12V/8ohm

Comment: "1H switched goes from 0A **to 1.5A** exponentially as 2H current goes from 3A **to 1.5A** exponentially " when opened

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 Yes, but that is the final condition. in a series circuit, **at all times** the current should be same in both inductors. Isn't it?

Comment: yes it is both the same 1.5A in series

Comment: No, it isn't. You yourself are saying that 1 H starts from 0 A, while  the 2H inductor starts from 3 A. \$3\neq 0\$. @TonyStewartEEsince1975 The fact that they finally both have the same current is quite obvious and doesn't answer my question.

Comment: good question ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may help to recognize that this is analogous to connecting capacitors charged to different voltages in parallel.  In the case of inductors it's conservation of flux rather than charge that is at play. So, by inspection, the current just after the switch opens will be 2/3 * I0.

As with the capacitor dual, you will also find that the energy is (apparently) not conserved because energy is lost in the switch opening. The energy in the inductors before the switch opening is 0.5*2*3^2 = 9J. The energy in the inductors after the switch opens is 0.5*2*2^2 + 0.5* 1* 2^2 = 8J.

Comment: Could you please say why you mention the word "apparently" there. In reality is energy conserved or lost as heat, in that case?

Comment: It's lost as heat and EM radiation, yes. Of course energy is conserved.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Charge should be conserved when two capacitors are brought parallel,

Flux should be conserved when two inductors are brought in series.

Equate the flux before and after switch was opened:

$$L_1I_{0^-} = (L_1+L_2)I_{0^+}$$

where \$I_{0^-} = 3A\$ , \$L1 = 2H \$ and \$L2 = 1H\$.

Means \$I_{0^+} = \frac{2}{3}I_{0^-} = 2A\$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Someone already answered the same thing sometime back ^. But I appreciate the help. :) It sucks that I can green tick only one answer though.

Answer (score 0):

at t=0 loop current stays at 3A and decays to steady state 1.5A

[**Simulation in Browser**](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%2013%200.00025499999999999996%209.001713130052181%2015%205%2043%0As%20192%20336%20336%20336%200%200%20false%0Al%20272%20208%20336%20208%200%202%202.9719489364992793%0Av%20192%20288%20192%20208%200%200%2040%2012%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20192%20208%20272%20208%200%204%0Al%20256%20288%20336%20288%200%201%20-0.0004877686144498559%0Ar%20256%20288%20192%20288%200%204%0Aw%20384%20336%20384%20288%200%0Ag%20192%20336%20192%20352%200%0Aw%20384%20288%20336%20288%201%0Aw%20336%20208%20384%20208%201%0Aw%20192%20336%20192%20288%200%0Aw%20384%20208%20384%20288%202%0Ax%20105%20329%20253%20332%204%2024%20press%5Cshere%5Cs%5Cq%3E%0Aw%20336%20336%20384%20336%201%0Ao%201%2064%200%204353%200.0000762939453125%203.2%200%202%201%203%202H%20current%0Ao%204%2064%200%204361%200.01953125%201.6%200%202%204%203%201H%20current%0A)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB1zPF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
[image]